# Execute javascript using QueryPath

Tags: javascript, querypath

I am using QueryPath to scrape some HTML files. Inside those HTML files there are some JS scripts enclosed in HTML comments. The JS will produce some textual content to be displayed to the screen, so I can't find (scrape) the textual content without executing the JS script.
Is it possible to execute the JS script using QueryPath?

Comment: will you please take some time to frame the question? please elaborate with the exact requirement? what have you done so far? got a snippet?

Comment: Yes, please clarify the question.  This does not give nearly enough context to answer properly.

Comment: sorry for this unclear question. @naveen I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just append your JS script to the html page.

```
qp(QueryPath::HTML_STUB)->append('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">alert("Hello!");</script>')->writeHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I haven't tried it, but I think this works for me.  I have found a way to extract the javascript content. I use this `next('div#id')->find('script[type="text/javascript"]')` for extracting. There are several scripts within those DIV element, but I can only get the first one. Do you know how to get all javascript content within the DIV element?

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is no way to execute JavaScript within QueryPath. The reason why is because PHP does not have access to either a browser `window` object or a JavaScript interpreter.

The best alternative I know of is to use Selenium (basically a browser remote controller) to run a browser, and then one of the PHP Selenium libraries to get the results. You can, of course, use QueryPath with the PHP Selenium library if you want.

Here's a decent overview of the PHP Selenium libraries: http://css.dzone.com/articles/selenium-2-php-code